# Как получить день недели из '20170703 '?

Tags: python, datetime

Как из даты в формате 20170703 получить день недели?

Пробовал так:

```
print('1data =', datetime.datetime.today().isoweekday('20170703'))
print('2data =', time.strptime(20170703))
print('3data =', datetime.datetime.weekday(20170703))
```

Comment: Что-то странное у вас, вот как надо `print(datetime.datetime.strptime('20170703', '%Y%m%d').isoweekday())`

Comment: Спасибо,  @andreymal!
Сработало. В хелпе не понял синтаксиса без примера. Ваш коммент помог понять конструкцию и синтаксис

Comment: @andreymal, ответы - в ответы.

Comment: @Qwertiy ой всё

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Парсим дату в объект datetime (время в этом объекте будет 0 часов без конкретного часового пояса, но нам это неважно):

```
>>> d = datetime.datetime.strptime('20170703', '%Y%m%d')
>>> print(d)
2017-07-03 00:00:00
>>> type(d)
<class 'datetime.datetime'>
```

Вызываем специальный метод [isoweekday](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.isoweekday) у этого объекта:

```
>>> print(d.isoweekday())
1
```

1..6 — понедельник..суббота соответственно, 7 — воскресенье *(иногда воскресенье обозначают нулём, но, если верить документации, не в isoweekday)*