# Python узнать день недели по дате

Tags: python, дата

Как(или фрагмент кода), что бы по дате узнать какой день недели был! например сегодня 15.01.2023 - Воскресенье,   15.01.2009 - какой день недели.

Comment: И еще [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1319128/%d0%98%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d1%87%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8c-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8), и [вот тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/813233/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8c-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7-20170703)

Comment: Фраза "я новичок" не является индульгенцией на ничегонеделание.

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_weekday(user_date):
user_date = datetime.strptime(user_date, "%y-%m-%d %H:%M")

weekday_num = datetime.isoweekday(user_date)
weekdays = {1: 'ПН',
            2: 'ВТ',
            3: 'СР',
            4: 'ЧТ',
            5: 'ПТ',
            6: 'СБ',
            7: 'ВС'}
return weekdays.get(weekday_num)
```

Answer (score -1):

Вы можете использовать класс `datetime` из стандартного модуля `datetime`:

```
from datetime import datetime

day = datetime.strptime("15.01.2009", "%d.%m.%Y")
day_of_weeek = day.weekday()
```

В результате вы получите в переменной `day_of_weeek` *номер дня в недели,* начиная с нуля:
`0` - понедельник, `1` - вторник, ..., `6` - воскресение.

---

Объяснение:

1. Класс `datetime` содержит метод `.strptime()`, который переводит дату в форме строки в объект типа `datetime`.
2. Когда вы уже имеете вашу дату в виде объекта типа `datetime` (в переменной `day`), вы получите удобство использовать различные методы этого класса, в вашем случае метод `weekday()`.
3. Второй параметр метода `.strptime()` - в нашем случае `"%d.%m.%Y"` - означает, что наша строка с датой (`"15.01.2009"`) в формате

   - день (`%d`), двузначный,
   - точка (`.`),
   - месяц (`%m`), двузначный,
   - точка (`.`),
   - год (`%Y`), четырёхзначный.